# how to get row-column pairs from sparse matrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

Say I have a sparse matrix M1

```
i<-c(1,5,2,4,2,2,8)
j<-c(2,5,3,2,4,2,4)
x<-rpois(7,2)
M1<-sparseMatrix(i,j,x=x)
rownames(M1) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h")
colnames(M1) <- c("L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5")
M1
```

where M1 looks like:

```
8 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
  L1 L2 L3 L4 L5
a  .  3  .  .  .
b  .  1  3  0  .
c  .  .  .  .  .
d  .  4  .  .  .
e  .  .  .  .  1
f  .  .  .  .  .
g  .  .  .  .  .
h  .  .  .  0  .
```

how would i make a set of interacting row-col pairs in a list that looks something like:

```
(a, L2)
(b, L2)
(b, L3)
(b, L4)
(d, L2)
(e, L5)
(h, L4)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want a list of values of your matrix or of the column and row names?

Comment: You are probably looking for `summary(M1)`.

Comment: as a complete aside, if you don't want to treat your `0` different from `.` you can use `drop0(M1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE` on a logical matrix and extract the row names and column names based on the `row/col` index

```
i1 <- which(M1 > 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
tibble(rn = row.names(M1)[i1[,1]], cn = colnames(M1)[i1[,2]]) %>%
    arrange(rn)
```

-ouptut

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  rn    cn   
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     L2   
2 b     L2   
3 b     L3   
4 b     L4   
5 d     L2   
6 e     L5   
7 h     L4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below

```
with(
  summary(t(M1)),
  data.frame(i = row.names(M1)[j], j = colnames(M1)[i])
)
```

which gives

```
  i  j
1 a L2
2 b L2
3 b L3
4 b L4
5 d L2
6 e L5
7 h L4
```